# Linear Regression: How to create proposital dependent erros in a covariance Matrix?

Tags: r, regression, montecarlo

I'm a undergraduate student of statistics and I'm writing an article in my scientific initiation that intents to be a pedagogical tool in R for professor to show to their beginner students a easy way to visualize graphically the importance of the Linear Regression Assumptions. This tool does not intend to substitutes the maths but only help visually.

The main idea is to replicates 1000 times the regression model deliberately violating the assumptions of the Linear Regression one by one, storing the statistics like Betahat's, P-value, R2 and others in a list.

After that the intention is to create charts like histograms, tables and scatter plots to illustrate graphically the behavior of the estimator when the assumptions are violated gradually. So other people(students or professors) can change the parameter as their desires to notice the importance of the assumptions.

I've already made the code to run the simulation in a Mont Carlo way for R to violate the Assumptions of Homocesdasticy and Normality of the errors.
But to violated the independence of the errors, I've somehow try to create a co-variance matrix if correlated errors but it doesn't seems to work well.

This is part of my code with anyone could take a look and help me to improve it I'll really appreciate that.

```
# Packages required to simulate multivariate normal distribution
install.packages("mvtnorm")
library(mvtnorm)

# Function that create the samples for the X:
X1 =  sample(0:20,30,T)
X2 =  sample(0:20,60,T)
X3 = sample(0:20,120,T)

# Function tha creates the vector with 1000 simulations for the Mont Carlo   

# Size of the samples

n1 <- 30
n2 <- 60
n3 <- 120

# Variations of the sigma to the simulation

S2.1 <- 0.5 
S2.2 <- 0.9

# Variations of the Ro to the function

Ro1 <- 0.8 
Ro2 <- 0.3
Ro3 <- - 0.8

# Base Zero Covariance matrix
cov1 <- matrix(0,n1,n1)
cov2 <- matrix(0,n2,n2)
cov3 <- matrix(0,n3,n3)

# Function that insert the dependence of errors in the covariance error Ei

M.Cov.Depen = function (n,cov,S2,Ro){
    diag(cov)= S2
    for (i in 1:n-1){
                    cov[i,i+1]= S2 * Ro
                    cov[i+1,i]= S2 * Ro
    }
    return(cov)
 }

# 1 - Covariance dependent Error Matrix with n=30, S2=0.5, Ro=0.8

 MCovD_n1_S2.1_Ro1 = M.Cov.Depen(n1,cov1,S2.1,Ro1)

# Function that creates the Dependece error with Normal Multivariate samples

Monte.Carlo.4 = function(X,n,Mcov){
    b0 = NULL;b1 = NULL;r2 = NULL;r2a = NULL;p = NULL;
    for (i in 1:1000) {
    Y = 1.4 + 0.8 * X + rmvnorm(1,mean=rep(0,n),sigma= Mcov)
    Y = as.vector(Y)
    s <- summary (lm(Y~X))
    b0 <- c(b0, s [[4]] [1])
    b1 <- c(b1, s [[4]] [2])
    r2 <- c(r2, s [[8]])
    p <- c(p, s[[4]] [8])
    }
    return (list(b0=b0,b1=b1,r2=r2,p=p))
}

# 1-  Vectors of Estimators with sigma=0.5, n=30, Ro=0.8:

Monte.4_n30_sig0.5_Ro0.8 <- Monte.Carlo.4(X1,30,cov1)
hist(Monte.4_n30_sig0.5_Ro0.8$r2)
dep.1 <- rmvnorm(30,sigma= cov1)
hist(dep.1)
cov1 <- matrix(Ro1 * S2.1,n1,n1)
diag(cov1)= 0.5
cov2 <- matrix(0,n2,n2)
cov3 <- matrix(0,n3,n3)

# Function that insert the dependence of errors in the covariance error Ei

M.Cov.Depen = function (n,cov,S2,Ro){
    for (i in 1:n){
                    cov[i,i]= S2 * Ro
    }
    diag(cov)= S2
    return(cov)
}

Y = 1.4 + 0.8 * X1 + rmvnorm(1,mean=rep(0,30),sigma= cov1)

plot(Y~X1)
dim(dep.1)
sigma <- matrix(c(4,2,2,3), ncol=2)
x <- rmvnorm(n=500, mean=c(1,2), sigma=sigma)
dim(Y)
plot(x)
```

I know its in some way unusual try to do something that a data annalist is not supposed to do but in opposite direction avoid it at any costs. But deconstructing the assumptions could be a way to understand and comprehend it better and help others to view the consequences of ignore it and fits a bad model.

Again I 'll appreciate any kind of help.